# Indentify old LEGO kit, classic car with bird driver

Tags: part-identification, fabuland

I have 2 parts left from a kit I had as a kid. I'm trying to find out what the kit was? I'm ALMOST sure the driver was a pose-able bird man, many thanks! [image]

Answer (score 9):

Looks like it could come from one of two Fabuland sets, [Bonnie Bunny's Camper](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=3635-1) or [Charlie Crow's Carry-All](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=3634-1). The radiator piece also comes in [The Fabuland House](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=3678-1).

Given your bird man as driver, I'm going with Charlie Crow's Carry-All.

Comment: @stacy if it's the match then feel free to accept